# impala how to create view from temp table?

Tags: sql, impala

I would like to create a view based on multiple temporary tables, I tried:

```
with t1 as (
        SELECT * 
        FROM mydb.my_existing_table 
        ),
        
    t2 as (
    SELECT * from t1)
   
    CREATE VIEW myotherdb.my_new_view AS  SELECT *  FROM t2
```

> ParseException: Syntax error in line 21:undefined: CREATE VIEW
> myotherdb.... ^ Encountered: CREATE Expected: INSERT, SELECT,
> UPSERT, VALUES, COMMA CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

I can rule out permission errors as this works:

```
CREATE VIEW myotherdb.my_new_view AS  SELECT * FROM mydb.my_existing_table
```

There must be some peculiar syntax that I missing when using temporary tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one probably should work:

```
CREATE VIEW myotherdb.my_new_view AS  
with t1 as (
        SELECT * 
        FROM mydb.my_existing_table 
        ),
        
    t2 as (
    SELECT * from t1)
SELECT *  FROM t2;
```